# Comment hint not disappearing when I start to type comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, internet-explorer-10

[image]

If I click "add comment", the comment hint (placeholder; *"Request clarification or add information."*) is not a hint, but editable text. If I delete the text and click outside of the comment then the hint appears as it should and when I click back into the comment box the hint disappears as it should.

I am on Internet Explorer 10.0.7.

Am I just oblivious and this is how it has always been (having to delete the comment hint), or is this a bug?

Comment: Definitely a bug. You shouldn't have to delete the comment hint manually.

Comment: Nope, shouldn't do that. Seeing same on Windows 7, same version of IE

Comment: Ha I was beginning to wonder after having not seen another bug report for this yet...

Comment: Mind you - this may be more of an IE bug than a SE bug... Will need to look into it.

Comment: @Oded Doesn't that really just say both are buggy, then? IE for its weirdness and SO for not compensating.

Comment: @GrantThomas - Does it? What if it turns out it is something that is completely wrong in one product, does that mean the other is also buggy?

Comment: @Oded Consequently so, yes.

Comment: @GrantThomas - So, if my appA produces invalid XML, that makes appB failing to read it buggy?

Comment: @Oded By proxy, yes - so long as the "fix" isn't in.

Comment: @GrantThomas - by your reasoning, by proxy, it is the users' fault ;)

Comment: Also occurs in IE 10.0.9200.16576, if it matters.

Comment: @Oded oddly enough, in IE10 the textarea contains both the placeholder and inner text, in Chrome only the placeholder. Maybe jQuery is to blame somehow?

Comment: Reproduced on IE 10.0.9200.16635.

Comment: This isn't a problem on Chrome Version 27.0.1453.116

Comment: Yep it's IE only problem. (IE10 for sure, probably IE9 as well though didn't test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is indeed specific to IE 10 textareas and how they handle placeholders (at least when added directly via jQuery), as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764607/html5-placeholder-attribute-on-textarea-via-jquery-in-ie10) seems to indicates.

Applied same solution, so the placeholder should start working correctly starting with revision 2013.7.22.875.

Comment: When will that revision take effect?

Comment: @TronicZomB - Whenever we deploy. Can be 5 minutes, can be a few hours. We don't have a schedule.

Comment: Yay, works for me :)