# Why doesn't the comment hint disappear in IE10, when using a touch device?

Tags: bug, comments

When you go to add a comment, the hint doesn't disappear if you're using touch gestures tap the "add comment" link. Not sure why this isn't using HTML5 hints instead, as that'd work (assuming that you're up to some browser sniffery).

Comment: I can’t tell where your first sentence begins and where it ends. What’s a comment hint?

Comment: This is a comment hint ->Notify others of updates or address concerns raised.

Comment: So you mean a placeholder? And you’re recommending that the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute be used? Well, it is…

Comment: @minitechη, indeed the HTML `placeholder` attribute *is* used, but note there's also a `data-placeholder` which I assume is used in some JavaScript, for browsers that do not support `placeholder`. Might very well be some SE JavaScript that is causing the problem?

Comment: @Arjan: [Who knows?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189538/comment-hint-not-disappearing-when-i-start-to-type-comment#comment585463_189538)