# New comment hint/placeholder becomes "undefined" when deleting all chars in edit mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-edits

I just noticed the new hint (placeholder) for comments:

- On SO: "Request clarification or suggest improvements."
- On Meta: "Request clarification or add information."/"Notify others of updates or address concerns raised."

But I also noticed a bug:

When you **remove all chars from a comment, when editing it** (after it has been created), the hint becomes "undefined".

[image: undefined placeholder]

Tested with:

- **Chrome 27.0.1453.116** 32-bit on Windows 8 64-bit
- **Chrome 28.0.1500.71** on Mac OS X 10.8.4
- **Firefox 21.0 32-bit** on Windows 8 64-bit

Related: [Comment hint not disappearing when I start to type comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189538/comment-hint-not-disappearing-when-i-start-to-type-comment)

Comment: ...verified!  Definitely present.

Comment: Confirmed, cool find.

Comment: Related: [Comment hint not disappearing when I start to type comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189538/comment-hint-not-disappearing-when-i-start-to-type-comment).

Comment: Lots of big problems with the comment text.

Comment: There was a minor change to this yesterday afternoon.  Is the behavior still present?  I haven't been able to reproduce it yet.

Comment: @BenCollins Did some tests here, and now the placeholder box becames empty (instead of `undefined`). I used Chrome and Firefox. I think it is gone. I'm at work right now, the computer I made the screenshots is at home. I will be there only by night, if you wish to wait, I can test again.

Comment: @acdcjunior: I suspect this was due to odd browser bugs as the question Arjan linked goes into.  Since Oded fixed that, I doubt this will be a problem again.  I'll mark this as status-complete, but if you see it again just leave a comment and I'll revisit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this bug was fixed by @Oded, as he explains in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189839/136973.  To summarize, it appears that several browsers do not like it when a `textarea` with a `placeholder` attribute already defined is inserted into the DOM.  Adding the `placeholder` attribute after the DOM insertion seems to clear it up.

Comment: Yeah. It is gone. No `undefined`. Keep in mind the original hint/placeholder is not back when we delete all chars. The textbox just becomes empty (in both places I got the bug)! This is it, I guess! Cheers!