# Comment textbox placeholder appears to be incomplete

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, user-interface

The placeholder text on Stack Overflow is:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like

So, what kind of comments should be avoided? I seem to recall that it was only

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.

before.

Screenshot:

[image]

I notice the same on Meta. Tested in latest Chrome and Firefox versions on OS X.

Comment: [[meta-tag:status-norepro]] on iPod Touch 4th gen iOS 5.1.1 using Safari - I see "Request clarification or add information."

Comment: Mmh. I see it Firefox and Chrome, OS X.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kyty.png @Doorknob

Comment: Better embed screenshot into the bug report.

Comment: Doesn't seem incomplete to me. It's telling *you* to avoid writing incomplete comments, like

Comment: What you did there, I see it.

Comment: @hjp Hmm, I would post a screenshot but I can from this iPod :P

Comment: Before it was "Notify others of updates or address concerns raised." as can be seen [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189778/152859). (this is one good side of so many bugs, lots of screenshots! :-))

Comment: And just yesterday it was "Request clarification or add more information." I think it's safe to say they're still trying to figure out what the text should be at all.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn if this is really the case, I am not sure if everyone gets this...

Comment: @sha I believe that was what it said on *your own answers*. Still says something similar.

Comment: [``](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190309/225020)

Comment: Maybe it means to avoid empty comments (like what I tried to do and failed [above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190309/comment-textbox-placeholder-appears-to-be-incomplete#comment589554_190309))

Comment: I just came here to ask this question. Placeholder below this comment is exactly same.

Comment: I get this too.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm all for trying to find the right text, as long as it is grammatically

Comment: This sentence no verb.

Comment: I don't usually post comments, but when I do

Comment: It's just an error in the HTML. The placeholder attributes have quotes in them, the same quotes as the delimiter quotes. Very simple error, really. Very beginner error too.

Comment: Unfortunately this little error breaks several scripts (as e.g. the [AutoReviewComments](https://gist.github.com/Benjol/842025/)). Luckily the cause was found and a fix be deployed soon. But usually, before deployment to production, shouldn't this

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's fixed and it will be out in the

Comment: ha ha, I was about to say something similar, like

Comment: I've just pushed the

Comment: ... deploy button

Comment: Wow, I can see the

Comment: Comment placeholders on own **answers** say *‘… edit your **question** …’*. Can that be fixed as easily as this one? Perhaps changing the wording to *‘edit your post’* would suffice. Or do I need to post the request as a new meta question?

Comment: @AndriyM New question, but I think there's already something open, please search first.

Comment: Haha, I see what you

Comment: You accidentally the

Answer (score 12):

I think the staff is trying to have different messages depending on whether the post is yours or not.

If you are the post owner, the comment placeholder is complete (see below)

[image: screenshot of comment placeholder]

But if it's not your post, the comment placeholder is incomplete.

I think the staff just

Comment: Yeah it definitely appears that they

Comment: You should clean your screen, it's apparently really dirty

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, looks fine on my screen. I think your screen

Comment: He's commenting on the fact that you used a blurry, highly-compressed JPEG for your screenshot

Comment: I tried to make it PNG but it stayed blurry because apparently you JPEG-compressed it *before* uploading, for some reason. At least it has more unicorn now.

Comment: @Doorknob: When else would one JPEG-compress an image?

Comment: @minitech IIRC, imgur keeps a jpeg and png version. (Also, nice edit comme