# Bug report: comment form's data-placeholdertext attribute text is not HTML-escaped

Tags: bug

From the HTML:

```
<td class="comment-form"><form id="add-comment-17854275" data-placeholdertext="Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks"."></form></td>
```

The quotes surrounding "+1" and "thanks" should be escaped to `&quot;`.

Comment: Hmm, where are you seeing this? [Everyone else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190309/comment-textbox-placeholder-appears-to-be-incomplete) just sees "Avoid comments like"

Comment: Yes, that's the same bug. I just reported the underlying reason - the text in the HTML isn't escaped.

Comment: Perhaps you should post this as an answer to that question, then? *"Here's the bug, and how you fix it"* type thing.

Comment: Didn't find the other questions, as I searched for the HTML attribute name... Anyway, looks like they've just fixed it.