# Comment on answer - hint is referring to question

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, answers, wording

The following hint is contained in the comment box of an **answer**, but is referring to editing the **question**...

[image]

In this particular case, I saw this on my answer to someone else's question. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003220/multiple-line-addition-in-tmemo/16003244#16003244). The answer of mine is showing this text if I were to post a comment to my own answer.

Comment: I believe that is only if you are the OP of the question...

Comment: @anorton In this case, I posted the answer, but not the question.

Comment: a link to the question would enable to check if others are facing the same problem

Comment: The message is appearing if you try to comment on your own post. Either question or answer. (Proof: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lzR1h.png )

Comment: when I see that example, I get "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like" and then there is nothing! So it might be a bug in any case

Comment: @Sai yes, that happens [right here on this page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T27ef.png). Presumably the text says something like `Avoid comments like "blah blah blah"` and uses the wrong, unescaped delimiter.

Comment: @AaronBertrand In fact it happens all over meta !!

Comment: @Sai yes, I didn't mean to imply *only* on this page. Just found it funny that I saw it immediately under your comment saying the same thing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I guess we should be asking a separate bug question since this would be unrelated to the bug the OP is encountering?

Comment: Yes, I think they are two separate bugs.

Comment: Changed to "Status-Completed" yet it still persists... Unless the code has been revised but hasn't been published yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep.  The wording should say "post" instead of "question" or "answer" to avoid this confusion.  Should be out in the next build.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I think that is clearer.

Comment: Yes, that definitely gets the point through while being universal

Answer (score 8):

Really, there are two bugs here. To address the one you mentioned:

When the textarea under your own *answer* shows that text, it should be talking about an **answer**, not a **question**.

To allow re-use, maybe the text should always use the word **post** across the board.

---

The other is that the text for commenting on someone *else's* post (both questions and answers, and across the network, not just on meta or SO) is truncated due to some kind of unescaped delimiter issue:

[image]

[This is a separate bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190309/comment-textbox-placeholder-appears-to-be-incomplete). Thanks, Tim.

Comment: The second part will be [fixed in the next deploy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190309/comment-textbox-placeholder-appears-to-be-incomplete), apparently.