# Tooltip for the rollback link is incomplete

Tags: bug, status-completed, rollbacks, tooltips

The tooltip text is currently:

"sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any"

[image: "sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any"]

I propose the sentence be completed.

Comment: View Source says the offending HTML attribute is `title="sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any "offensive" flags"`, making it the same class of bug as the [*"Avoid comments like "*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190309/comment-textbox-placeholder-appears-to-be-incomplete#comment589825_190309) fiasco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad here. Didn't catch the embedded `"`s when localizing this page.

Fixed in the next build, later today.